# Running Tensorflow on multiple gpu's

Tags: tensorflow

I have checked the website but as always it was not clear for me. Can anyone describes all of the steps (from very beginning) to run any tensorflow program on GPU's?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Tensorflow official site:
https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/using_gpu

```
# Creates a graph.
c = []
for d in ['/device:GPU:2', '/device:GPU:3']:
  with tf.device(d):
    a = tf.constant([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0], shape=[2, 3])
    b = tf.constant([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0], shape=[3, 2])
    c.append(tf.matmul(a, b))
with tf.device('/cpu:0'):
  sum = tf.add_n(c)
# Creates a session with log_device_placement set to True.
sess = tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=True))
# Runs the op.
print(sess.run(sum))
```